# Variable weight calculation

Tags: linear-regression, data-science

I am looking for algorithms that assign weights to some variables based on an outcome. You have a response variable Y, let's say the sales generated by a customer and some explanatory variables related to each customer. I want to attribute a value/weight to each of these variables.

I started with fitting a linear regression algorithm but R squared was not so attractive. Is there any suggestions concerning some other models doing the same thing but maybe with more precision?

For example for [Linear regression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwFLl.png) the beta values are the weights I am looking for.

Comment: I suggest visually inspecting scatterplots of the response variable Y versus each explanatory variable to determine if there is any obvious data transformation such as log that might improve precision - this has the advantage of being fast and easy to perform.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming